# How do I prevent HTTPS on a subdirectory of WordPress with Apache Rules?

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

My goal is to redirect all pages of my website to HTTPS if the user is trying to access HTTP, **unless** the page being accessed is under `http://example.com/wc-api/`. (Including all subdirectories of `wc-api`.)

These are my rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\/?wc-api.* - [END]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

The problem is that while all pages *not* in the subdirectory are redirected to https as expected, any pages within `wc-api` are returning `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`.

I expect that this might be because the subdirectory `wc-api` does not actually exist. Instead, it is a REST API of WooCommerce. However, if I disable all of these rules, I can access the /wc-api/ subdirectory and it works as expected (despite it not physically existing).

Since the above rules did not work, I also tried just using a negative pattern condition on the HTTPS RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/?wc-api.*
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

In this case however, the page is then sent on to be evaluated by the `.htaccess` file in the root of WordPress and then is redirected to the index page of my website because of this rule:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Here is my WordPress `.htaccess` file:

```
## Default .htaccess file

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF

# BEGIN WP Performance Score Booster Settings

## BEGIN Enable GZIP Compression ##
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</IfModule>
## END Enable GZIP Compression ##


## BEGIN Vary: Accept-Encoding Header ##
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
## END Vary: Accept-Encoding Header ##


## BEGIN Expires Caching (Leverage Browser Caching) ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 2 week"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 2 week"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 week"
</IfModule>
## END Expires Caching (Leverage Browser Caching) ##

# END WP Performance Score Booster Settings
```

I really don't know what to do. I've tried every combination I can think of. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

What about this code? In my environment it works like a charm:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule !^wc-api.* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```